# try except if two inputs are the same

Tags: python, input, duplicates, try-catch, except

I currently have a while loop that looks like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        entry1 = input("input the first number")
        entry2 = input("enter the second number")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("number must be valid re-enter")
```

I want to add code that will reprompt the user to enter two different numbers if the user decides to enter two numbers that are the same. I tried using the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        entry1 = input("input the first number")
        entry2 = input("enter the second number")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("number must be valid re-enter")
    try: 
        if entry1 == entry2:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            break
    except ValueError as err:
        print("The two numbers cant be the same. re-enter two unique numbers!"
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Does anyone know what is going wrong with my code?

Comment: Break is placed incorectly

Comment: If you're using python 3, you need to wrap your input calls with int or float (otherwise you're exceptions will never be reached)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `assert` method to make sure the 2 inputs are different and catch with `AssertionError` if they don't.

```
while True:
    try:
        entry1 = int(input("input the first number"))
        entry2 = int(input("enter the second number"))
        assert entry1 != entry2
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("number must be valid re-enter")
    except AssertionError:
        print("The two numbers cant be the same. re-enter two unique numbers!")
```

Answer (score 1):

For what you are describing you don't need all these exceptions. You could for example just use the comparison as condition for a while loop:

```py
entry1 = entry2 = 0
while entry1 == entry2:
    entry1 = input("input the first number")
    entry2 = input("enter the second number")
    if entry1 == entry2:
        print("The two numbers can't be the same. re-enter two unique numbers!")
```

Edit:
Of course it makes sense to cast the input to int and catch the error if that doesn't work. That could be like this:

```py
entry1 = entry2 = 0
while entry1 == entry2:
    try:
        entry1 = int(input("input the first number"))
        entry2 = int(input("enter the second number"))
        if entry1 == entry2:
            print("The two numbers can't be the same. re-enter two unique numbers!")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter valid numbers")
```

Comment: I want to keep the valueError except method in. Is there another way I can troubleshoot around two duplicate entries?

Comment: I added a try/except in case the input is not an integer. Maybe that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`break` are called incorrectly. Too many `try-except` block.

```
 while True:
    try:
        entry1 = input("input the first number: ")
        entry2 = input("enter the second number: ")
    except ValueError:
        print("number must be valid re-enter.")

    if entry1 == entry2:
            print("The two numbers cant be the same. re-enter two "
                  "uniquen numbers!")
    else :
        break
```

Comment: would I need to put the break in the else: statement? If i left it in that if statement the loop would end without remprompting the user for entry

Comment: yes you are right. Put the break in else part. So if the numbers are not equal then it will break the loop.